# Django Static Files Not Being Found (debug off)

Tags: python, django, nginx

I cannot get Django to correctly reference my static files when debug is off. I know there are many other posts on this site about this, but none of them have fixed my issue.

My directory tree is like this:

```
└── project
    └── app1
    └── app1
    ├── manage.py
    └── project
    └── project.sock
    └── projectenv
    └── static
    └── template
```

In my `settings.py` I have the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

In my nginx configuration file I have the following:

```
location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/myproject/static/;
}
```

running `./manage.py collectstatic` correctly places all my files into the static directory.

however, in running my server, all of these static files 404:

```
[22/Jul/2016 17:05:31] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 6418
[22/Jul/2016 17:05:31] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 6418
[22/Jul/2016 17:05:31] "GET /static/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 6418
[22/Jul/2016 17:05:31] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 6418
```

The static files are placed in the same directory as my manage.py file. What am I doing wrong?

Adding this in my urls.py does work, but aren't I supposed to serve them directly from nginx instead?

```
if settings.DEBUG is False:   #if DEBUG is True it will be served automatically
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

> It's slower since static files rendering goes through Django instead
>   served by your web server directly

Comment: Can you list your project directory structure here?

Comment: Is your applications static files being served? Can you also check the permissions of the `static` directory?

Comment: I do not know nginx but that looks like very little coding compared to what is required to serve with Apache.  Take a look at the Apache example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: The static directory has the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your nginx: edit nginx.conf the following way: add this:

```
location ~* ^(/static/|/media/).+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|zip|eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    root /path/to/parent/folder/of/static/folder;
}
```

to the `server {` clause corresponding to your website, then restart nginx and it should fix your problem, if not - check nginx logs, make sure that the folder has appropriate permissions for nginx user/group etc

Comment: How is this regular expression different from my current configuration? Shouldn't when a url starts with static point to my directory now?